# ClamAV occur error socket_connect(): unable to connect [13]: Permission denied?

Tags: php, centos, centos7

My OS: Centos 7, using laravel 5.8, php 7.1:

I using Clamav.php at: https://github.com/kissit/php-clamav-scan
to scan virus of a file:

Changed setting of socket file:

```
private $clamd_sock = "/var/run/clamd.scan/clamd.sock";
```

This is my simple code in laravel:

```
    $clamav = new Clamav();
    echo "Testing a bad file...\n";
    if($clamav->scan("/var/www/html/test/storage/logs/clamav_test.txt")) {
        echo "YAY, file is safe!\n";
    } else {
        echo "BOO, file is a virus.  Message: " . $clamav->getMessage() . "\n";
    }
```

i had install clamav on centos 7 by url: https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-install-clamav-centos7

i had setting:

```
sudo setsebool -P daemons_enable_cluster_mode 1
```

and had add user `apache` to `clamscan` group

```
sudo usermod -a -G clamscan apache
```

I had check exist file socket:

```
[root@ip-172-31-2-17 centos]# ls -l /var/run/clamd.scan/
total 0
srw-rw-rw-. 1 clamscan clamscan 0 Sep 19 20:49 clamd.sock
```

But it occur error:

> socket_connect(): unable to connect [13]: Permission denied
> [image]

How can fix this problem?

Comment: Shouldn't you add www-data user to clamscan

Comment: can fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this solution, it works for me

```
chmod 755 /var/run/clamd.scan
```

I've tried with docker.

supervisord.conf:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:httpd]
redirect_stderr=true
command=/usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
process_name = httpd

[program:clamd]
directory=/
command=clamd -c /etc/clamd.d/scan.conf &
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:7

# Install Apache
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install httpd httpd-tools

# Install EPEL Repo
RUN rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm \
 && rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm

# Install PHP
RUN yum -y install php71w php71w-bcmath php71w-cli php71w-common php71w-gd php71w-intl php71w-ldap php71w-mbstring \
    php71w-mysql php71w-pear php71w-soap php71w-xml php71w-xmlrpc

RUN yum -y install git

RUN yum -y install clamav-server clamav-data clamav-update clamav-filesystem clamav clamav-scanner-systemd clamav-devel clamav-lib clamav-server-systemd wget

RUN yum -y install php71w-devel gcc make
RUN yum -y groupinstall "Development tools"

#RUN wget https://datapacket.dl.sourceforge.net/project/php-clamav/0.15/php-clamav_0.15.7.tar.gz
#RUN tar -xvzf php-clamav_0.15.7.tar.gz && cd php-clamav-0.15.7 && phpize && ./configure && make && make install

RUN sed -E -i -e '/<Directory "\/var\/www\/html">/,/<\/Directory>/s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
RUN sed -E -i -e 's/DirectoryIndex (.*)$/DirectoryIndex index.php \1/g' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

RUN sed -i -e "s/^Example/#Example/" /etc/clamd.d/scan.conf
RUN sed -i 's+#LocalSocket /var/run/clamd.scan/clamd.sock+LocalSocket /var/run/clamd.scan/clamd.sock+g' /etc/clamd.d/scan.conf

RUN cat /etc/clamd.d/scan.conf | grep clamd.sock

RUN sed -i -e "s/^Example/#Example/" /etc/freshclam.conf
RUN freshclam

RUN chmod 755 /var/run/clamd.scan

RUN yum -y install supervisor
RUN yum -y install mc

COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisord.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]

CMD ["supervisord", "-n"]
```

index.php

```
<?php
require 'Clamav.php';
$sock = "/var/run/clamd.scan/clamd.sock";
if (file_exists($sock)){
    echo "";
}else{
    echo "$sock not found";
}

$clamav = new Clamav(array('clamd_sock' => $sock));

if($clamav->scan("/var/www/html/scan.txt")) {
    echo "YAY, file is safe\n";
} else {
    echo "BOO, file is a virus.  Message: " . $clamav->getMessage() . "\n";
}

?>
```

See [here](http://huckleberry.mhu.edu/randommusings/index.php/2016/08/01/centos-7-and-clamav/)

Comment: Thank you, this command had working: chmod 755 /var/run/clamd.scan, but after reboot vps, it occur error again, i have to run chmod again, Can i set permission 1 time?

Comment: Have you tried `chmod +x /etc/rc.d/rc.local` then adding `chmod 755 /var/run/clamd.scan` at the bottom of /etc/rc.d/rc.local? https://www.tecmint.com/auto-execute-linux-scripts-during-reboot-or-startup/

Comment: Creating a simple service? https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-7-how-to-make-custom-script-to-run-automatically-during-boot/

Comment: Thank you, i had edit permission in this config and it working ok: /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/clamd.scan.conf

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on Ubuntu 22.04 recently. I did able to fix it by running

```
dpkg-reconfigure clamav-daemon
```

This reconfigure ClamAV and set the socket.